# Getting an error 'no file named tf_model.h5 or pytorch_model.bin found in directory gpt2'

Tags: tensorflow, text, pytorch, classification, gpt-2

```
model_name = "gpt2"
model = TFGPT2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
```

When I am running the above code, the model is downloaded successfully.

Once the model is downloaded, I am defining the model configuration and loading the model with the updated configuration which throws an error 'OSError: Error no file named tf_model.h5 or pytorch_model.bin found in directory gpt2-medium.'

```
#Define model configuration
model_config = model.config
model_config.num_labels = 5

#Save model configuration
model_config.save_pretrained(model_name)

#Load model with updated configuration
model = TFGPT2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels =5)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If your model directory doesn't have `tf_model.h5` or `pytorch_model.bin` files as the error suggests, but ***does*** have a `model.safetensors` file or similar, first confirm you have `safetensors` installed:

```py
import importlib.util
print(importlib.util.find_spec("safetensors") is not None)
```

Otherwise install it:

```bash
!pip install safetensors
```

If errors persist, try:

```py
!pip install 'transformers[torch]'
```

Things should work after resolving any dependency issues and restarting your kernel to reload modules. For reference, I was able to load a fine-tuned `distilroberta-base` and its corresponding `model.safetensors` file with the following:

```bash
!pip install accelerate==0.24.1
!pip install huggingface-hub==0.17.3 
!pip install safetensors==0.4.0 
!pip install tokenizers==0.14.1 
!pip install transformers==4.35.0
```

```py
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(<model_path>)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(<tokenizer_path>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the "pytorch_model.bin" or "tf_model.h5" file is available in your downloaded repo.

Or maybe the path isn't correct.